What is the purpose of the "Workpoints" appended to Durrell's Justine?
At the end of Lawrence Durrell's Justine (1957, rev. 1962) is a brief appendix called "Workpoints." They appear to be either Durrell's jottings about his characters and settings, or outtakes from the novel. For example, there is a list of characters with curt summaries:

CHARACTER-SQUEEZES
Sveva Magnani: pertness, malcontent
Gaston Pombal: honey-bear, fleshly opiates.
Teresa di Petromonti: farded Berenice.
Ptolomeo Dandolo: astronomer, astrologer, Zen.
 Durrell, Lawrence. Justine. 1957, rev. 1962. The Alexandra Quartet pp. 13–203. With a new introduction by Jan Morris. London: Faber and Faber, 2012. p. 197.

... and so on. Some of these characters (such as the last two named above) do not appear in the novel itself. For some of the others, we are given information that isn't in the novel proper. E.g., we learn that Nissim and Justine's last name is Hosnani, and Melissa's Artemis.
The outtakes consist of brief paragraphs or even single sentences:

Balthazar on Justine: "You will find that her formidable manner is constructed on a shaky edifice of childish timidities."
ibid., p. 198

The section ends with Durrell's somewhat overwrought translations of two poems by Constantin Cavafy, "The City" and "The God Abandons Antony."
What is the point of this section? Why introduce new characters in this fashion, with just their name and a phrase of description? Why provide information that seems irrelevant after the action has concluded, such as the last names of other characters? Why are there snippets of dialogue that would have fitted in quite well with the main portion of the novel, but seem out of context here? What structural or thematic purpose does the Workpoints section serve? Is it a teaser for subsequent volumes of the tetralogy?
